# java.awt.Point translate un-doing itself

Tags: java, point

I have the following code with `start` and `end` each of the type `java.awt.Point`.

```
start.translate(-1, 0);
end.translate(1, 0);
```

However, when I run this code with `start = (0, 0) end = (0, 0)`, both `start` and `end` turn out as `(0, 0)`. Why is this happening, and is it only me?

**EDIT** Even more strangely, when I look at the coordinates before line 2 and after line 1, both points `start` and `end` are at `(-1, 0)`; essentially, `translate(int x, int y)` translated both points!

Comment: Could it be that `start` and `end` refer to the same object? That would explain why they are both transformed, and the result is (0,0) after translating them -1 and 1 in the x-axis. Please show the code that creates the `start` and `end` objects.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt Actually, that is the problem! I just checked over my code, and they are referring to the same object in an array! Post this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way this could happen is that the `start` and `end` variable point to the exact same object. And so, after the point (0,0) is translated by -1 in the x-coordinate, and then again by +1, you get (0,0) again. Check the code which creates the `start` and `end` objects.